# I need to write a dynamic XPath for below scenario

Tags: xpath

HTML Code:
`<font size="6.2em;" color="red"> $0.00</font>`[image: page screenshot]

I need to print the price every time I add more items.

The XPath that I've tried is
`*//font[starts-with(normalize-space()='$')]*` but it is not locating price tag element.

this is the URL : http://demo.guru99.com/payment-gateway/process_purchasetoy.php

Comment: In your xpath, `starts-with()` takes two parameters, one is missing. Try this instead `//*[@id='three']/div/form/div[1]/div/font[2]`

Comment: Does absolute xpath impacts performance?

Comment: absolute path is faster

Comment: What if the position of the element chages in future.

Comment: you can do something less specific, like  `"//font[starts-with(normalize-space(text()),'$')]"` but if they add another font with `$` on that page, that would also be a problem. So another option is `"//*[@id='three']//font[starts-with(normalize-space(text()), '$')]"`

Comment: Thanks a ton for a quick response 